# How to use callbacks in Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

So let's say I have the following code:

```
public function first(text:String):String {
   _text = text;
   dispatchEvent(event);

   //Want this statement to return the value of _text
   //after handler has finished transforming text.
   return _text;
}

//handles the event
public function handler(event:Event):void {
   //does things, then changes the value of _text
   _text = "next text that first needs to return";
}
```

How would I make sure the method (first) returns the correct value of _text after it has been transformed by (handler)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ActionScript uses the format `name:Type` for arguments, not `Type name`.

Comment: I had right in event but I am switching too much between flex and java, this the confusion. Thanks for pointing that out though :)

Comment: Yeah I have the same problem between this and C# :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ActionScript is single-threaded language and event handlers don't return value I assume that your code will work if _text is variable in package scope. Next code doesn't make a big sense, but if you call `first` function from another class it can be useful

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class EventTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function EventTest()
        {
            addEventListener("sliceText", sliceHandler);

            //will be Some
            var newText:String = first("SomeText");
            trace(newText);
        }

        private var _text:String;

        public function first(text:String):String
        {
            _text = text;

            dispatchEvent(new Event("sliceText"));

            return _text;
        }

        protected function sliceHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            //let's slice text to be more valuable
            _text = _text.slice(0,4);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: once you dispatch the event, (first) will not be waiting to get the result back and it will simply return the previous value of _text, right?

Comment: Nope, as I said, ActionScript is single-threaded language, which means if you dispatch an event the process will go to it's listeners and only after all listeners ends up their execution, the process will be on next after dispatching instruction. So in my example sliceHandler will be launched before return statement.